# sidebar-toggle adminlte not work in yii2

Tags: yii2, adminlte

How can I fix my left side navigation. I am using AdminLTE 2.0in yii2 framework.

The problem is, the toggle side-bar not work after i do `composer update` yesterday (9.00 am Malaysia time).

I suspect the error must happen from javascript.

But could not find any.

Therefore, i give you my code to discuss here.

Thank You

backend\views\layout\header.php

```html
<?php
use backend\assets\AppAsset;
use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\bootstrap\Nav;
use yii\bootstrap\NavBar;

/* @var $this \yii\web\View */
/* @var $content string */

AppAsset::register($this);
?>

<header class="main-header">
    <a href="../../index2.html" class="logo">
        <!-- mini logo for sidebar mini 50x50 pixels -->
        <span class="logo-mini"><b>A</b>U</span>
        <!-- logo for regular state and mobile devices -->
        <span class="logo-lg"><b>A</b>uTem</span>
    </a>
<!-- 
<?= Html::a(Yii::$app->name, Yii::$app->homeUrl, ['class' => 'logo']) ?> -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-static-top" role="navigation">
        <a href="#" class="sidebar-toggle" data-toggle="offcanvas" role="button">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </a>
        <!-- Navbar Right Menu -->
        <div class="navbar-custom-menu">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <!-- Messages: style can be found in dropdown.less-->
                <li class="dropdown messages-menu">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                        <i class="fa fa-envelope-o"></i>
                        <span class="label label-success">4</span>
                    </a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li class="header">You have 4 messages</li>
                        <li>
                            <!-- inner menu: contains the actual data -->
                            <ul class="menu">
                                <li><!-- start message -->
                                    <a href="#">
                                        <div class="pull-left">
                            <img src="<?= $directoryAsset ?>/img/avatar2.png" class="img-circle" alt="user image"/>
                        </div>
                        <h4>
                            AdminLTE Design Team
                            <small><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> 2 hours</small>
                        </h4>
                        <p>Why not buy a new awesome theme?</p>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">
                        <div class="pull-left">
                            <img src="<?= $directoryAsset ?>/img/avatar.png" class="img-circle" alt="user image"/>
                        </div>
                        <h4>
                            Developers
                            <small><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> Today</small>
                        </h4>
                        <p>Why not buy a new awesome theme?</p>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">
                        <div class="pull-left">
                            <img src="<?= $directoryAsset ?>/img/avatar2.png" class="img-circle" alt="user image"/>
                        </div>
                        <h4>
                            Sales Department
                            <small><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> Yesterday</small>
                        </h4>
                        <p>Why not buy a new awesome theme?</p>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">
                        <div class="pull-left">
                            <img src="<?= $directoryAsset ?>/img/avatar.png" class="img-circle" alt="user image"/>
                        </div>
                        <h4>
                            Reviewers
                            <small><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> 2 days</small>
                        </h4>
                        <p>Why not buy a new awesome theme?</p>
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="footer"><a href="#">See All Messages</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
<!-- Notifications: style can be found in dropdown.less -->
<li class="dropdown notifications-menu">
    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
        <i class="fa fa-warning"></i>
        <span class="label label-warning">10</span>
    </a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li class="header">You have 10 notifications</li>
        <li>
            <!-- inner menu: contains the actual data -->
            <ul class="menu">
                <li>
                    <a href="#">
                        <i class="ion ion-ios7-people info"></i> 5 new members joined today
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">
                        <i class="fa fa-warning danger"></i> Very long description here that may not fit into the page
                        and may cause design problems
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">
                        <i class="fa fa-users warning"></i> 5 new members joined
                    </a>
                </li>

                <li>
                    <a href="#">
                        <i class="ion ion-ios7-cart success"></i> 25 sales made
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">
                        <i class="ion ion-ios7-person danger"></i> You changed your username
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="footer"><a href="#">View all</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
<!-- Tasks: style can be found in dropdown.less -->
<li class="dropdown tasks-menu">
    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
        <i class="fa fa-tasks"></i>
        <span class="label label-danger">9</span>
    </a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li class="header">You have 9 tasks</li>
        <li>
            <!-- inner menu: contains the actual data -->
            <ul class="menu">
                <li><!-- Task item -->
                    <a href="#">
                        <h3>
                            Design some buttons
                            <small class="pull-right">20%</small>
                        </h3>
                        <div class="progress xs">
                            <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-aqua" style="width: 20%" role="progressbar"
                                 aria-valuenow="20" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100">
                                <span class="sr-only">20% Complete</span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <!-- end task item -->
                <li><!-- Task item -->
                    <a href="#">
                        <h3>
                            Create a nice theme
                            <small class="pull-right">40%</small>
                        </h3>
                        <div class="progress xs">
                            <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-green" style="width: 40%" role="progressbar"
                                 aria-valuenow="20" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100">
                                <span class="sr-only">40% Complete</span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <!-- end task item -->
                <li><!-- Task item -->
                    <a href="#">
                        <h3>
                            Some task I need to do
                            <small class="pull-right">60%</small>
                        </h3>
                        <div class="progress xs">
                            <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-red" style="width: 60%" role="progressbar"
                                 aria-valuenow="20" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100">
                                <span class="sr-only">60% Complete</span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <!-- end task item -->
                <li><!-- Task item -->
                    <a href="#">
                        <h3>
                            Make beautiful transitions
                            <small class="pull-right">80%</small>
                        </h3>
                        <div class="progress xs">
                            <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-yellow" style="width: 80%" role="progressbar"
                                 aria-valuenow="20" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100">
                                <span class="sr-only">80% Complete</span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <!-- end task item -->
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="footer">
            <a href="#">View all tasks</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
<?php
if (Yii::$app->user->isGuest) {
    ?>
    <li class="footer">
        <?= Html::a('Login', ['/site/login']) ?>
    </li>
<?php
} else {
    ?>
    <li class="dropdown user user-menu">
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i>
            <span><?= @Yii::$app->user->identity->username ?> <i class="caret"></i></span>
        </a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <!-- User image -->
            <li class="user-header light-blue">
                <img src="<?= $directoryAsset ?>/img/avatar5.png" class="img-circle" alt="User Image"/>

                <p>
                    <?= @Yii::$app->user->identity->username ?> - Web Developer
                    <small>Member since Nov. 2012</small>
                </p>
            </li>
            <!-- Menu Body -->
            <li class="user-body">
                <div class="col-xs-4 text-center">
                    <a href="#">Followers</a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-4 text-center">
                    <a href="#">Sales</a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-4 text-center">
                    <a href="#">Friends</a>
                </div>
            </li>
            <!-- Menu Footer-->
            <li class="user-footer">
                <div class="pull-left">
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-default btn-flat">Profile</a>
                </div>
                <div class="pull-right">
                    <?= Html::a(
                            'Sign out',
                            ['/site/logout'],
                            ['data-method' => 'post','class'=>'btn btn-default btn-flat']
                        ) ?>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li><?php
}
?>
<!-- User Account: style can be found in dropdown.less -->

</ul>
</div>
</nav>
</header>
```

backend\assets\AppAsset.php

```html
<?php
/**
 * @link http://www.yiiframework.com/
 * @copyright Copyright (c) 2008 Yii Software LLC
 * @license http://www.yiiframework.com/license/
 */

namespace backend\assets;

use yii\web\AssetBundle;

/**
 * @author Qiang Xue <qiang.xue@gmail.com>
 * @since 2.0
 */
class AppAsset extends AssetBundle
{
    public $basePath = '@webroot';
    public $baseUrl = '@web';
    public $css = [
        'css/site.css',
    ];
    public $js = [
        'js/highcharts.js',
        'js/exporting.js',
        'js/graphDashboard.js',
        'js/jquery.dataTables.bootstrap.js',
        'js/jquery.dataTables.min.js',
        'js/manageAlumni.js',
        'js/viewReport.js',
        'js/managefaculty.js',
        'js/managecourse.js',
        'js/statisticAlumni.js',
        'js/advSearch.js',
        'js/app.min.js',


    ];
    public $depends = [
        'yii\web\YiiAsset',
        'yii\bootstrap\BootstrapAsset',
        //'fedemotta\datatables\DataTablesAsset',
    ];
}
```

Comment: Did you inspect in your browser for any js error ?  When u click toggle button , a class `sidebar-collapse` is added to body tag. That's how it works.

Comment: @ck_arjun i found the code. the error on console : jquery.dataTables.bootstrap.js:2 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'defaults' of undefined

Comment: Have you resolved this error? If yes then please share, I am getting issue, if I click then it slides up and down automatically on first click But after that works fine.

Answer (score 7):

Try to replace

```
data-toggle="offcanvas"
```

with

```
data-toggle="push-menu"
```

Answer (score 2):

try to change composer.json

```
"dmstr/yii2-adminlte-asset": "2.*"
to
"dmstr/yii2-adminlte-asset": "2.4.4"
```

and then run `"composer update"`

this will solve menu toggle and menu tree view problems.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on Admin-LTE 2.4.x,

Add data-widget="tree" to the sidebar menu. Specifically, it should look like this:

```
<ul class="sidebar-menu" data-widget="tree">
```

and
If your Sidebar Toggle is not working, do:
Change

```
data-toggle="offcanvas" to data-toggle="push-menu"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).on('click', '[data-toggle="push-menu"]', function () {
    if (!$('body').hasClass("sidebar-collapse") && $('body').hasClass("sidebar-open")) {
        $('body').removeClass("sidebar-open");
        $('body').addClass("sidebar-collapse");
        $('body').addClass("sidebar-mini");
    //console.log('menu kapa');
    } else if($('body').hasClass("sidebar-collapse")) {
        $('body').removeClass("sidebar-collapse");
        $('body').addClass("sidebar-open");
    //console.log('menu ac');
    } else {
        $('body').addClass("sidebar-collapse");
        $('body').addClass("sidebar-open");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery

```
$('[data-widget="pushmenu"]').on('click', function (){
        $('[data-widget="pushmenu"]').PushMenu("toggle");
    });
```